# "Dem Bus" and "fahren" in a sentence

Tags: dative

Why do we use "dem Bus" with "fahren" where "dem Bus" is Dativ and "fahren" is Akkusativ.

Comment: We don't. You've probably omitted a preposition from your example - prepositions are also words that induce case in other words.

Comment: I would be helpful you if also say us the sentence which you have in mind.

Comment: BTW "fahren" is not Akkusativ. "Fahren" is a verb and verbs have no grammatical cases.

Comment: What exctly are you talking about? Tell us a sentence where you believe, that *Bus* is in dative case while *fahren* is accusative. Your Questions is useless without an example.

Comment: @userunknown Genau anders herum: man fragt nach einem _Dativ_-Objekt mit 'Wem? - Dem Bus."  und nach einem _Akkusativ_-Objekt mit "Wen oder was? - Den Bus".

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Mist, das verhaue ich immer wieder. Nicht in der Benutzung, sondern nur in der Bezeichnung. Danke, ich korrigiere: Akkusativ ist 'wen oder was', also 'Den Bus zu fahren haben ich gelernt', oder 'Möchten Sie auch mal den Bus fahren'. 'Dem Bus' →Wem-Fall, Dativ, 'Dem Bus habe ich das Fahren nachhaltig ausgetrieben (Getriebeschaden).' Fahren ist hier jedoch Substantiv. :) 'Dem Busfahren bin dank meines Rennrads entwöhnt.' - wieder ein Substantiv. 'Dem Bus fahre ich mit dem Rennrad allemal davon.' Da, jetzt hat es doch noch geklappt!

Answer (score 7):

Indeed the sentence where the word "*Bus*" is used with the verb "*fahren*" would be:

> Ich fahre de**n** Bus.

This sentence (which means that I am the driver of the bus and not a passenger) clearly uses accusative.

In your example however the word "*Bus*" belongs to the word "*mit*" and **not** to the verb "*fahren*" itself:

> Ich fahre **mit** dem Bus.

As far as I know the word "*mit*" is always formed with a dative - independent of the verb used.

Answer (score 2):

### A verb itself never stands in any grammatical case.

The verb is the ruler of the sentence, and it dictates which cases its complements must have.

All verbs need a subject as one of its complements, and this subject is always in nominative case:

> Klaus schläft.
>   Dieter fährt.

And all verbs can have additional complements, and for some verbs additional complements are mandatory.

> Anna gedenkt der Toten.
>   Das Buch gehört der Bibliothek.
>   Das neue Kleid passt.
>   Das neue Kleid passt meiner Frau.
>   Hans fährt.
>   Hans fährt einen Diesel.

- *»gedenken«* needs a mandaroty subject in nominative case (*»Anna«*) and a mandatory genitive object (*»der Toten«*)
- *»gehören«* needs a mandaroty subject in nominative case (*»das Buch«*) and a mandatory dative object (*»der Bibliothek«*)
- *»passen«* needs a mandaroty subject in nominative case (*»das neue Kleid«*) and it can have an optional dative object (*»meiner Frau«*)
- *»fahren«* needs a mandaroty subject in nominative case (*»Hans«*) and it can have an optional accusative object (*»einen Diesel«*)

Most verbs also can have prepositional objects

> Berta geht in den Keller.
>   Das Buch liegt auf dem Tisch.
>   Hans denkt an einen Apfel.
>   Susanne fährt mit dem Bus.

The parts *»in den Keller«, »auf dem Tisch«, »an einen Apfel«* and *»mit dem Bus«* are prepositional objects. They consist of a preposition and an Object in dative or accusative case, that is embedded in the prepositional objects. The case of this inner object is not determined by the verb. Inside a prepositional object the preposition determines the case of the inner object.

In the examples above *»in«, »an«* and *»auf«* can take their complements in both cases, but with different meanings. This can be limited by the verb (*»denken an«* needs accusative, but *»befestigen an«* can come with both cases). *»Mit«* always needs its complement in dative case.

And many verbs allow multiple complements:

> Gerd gönnt sich in seinem Schaukelstuhl ein Gläschen Wein.

Here the verb *gönnen* has four complements:

- *Gerd*
  mandatory subject in nominative case
- *sich*
  mandatory accusative object
- *in seinem Schaukelstuhl*
  optional prepositional object
- *sich*
  mandatory dative object

Sometimes there can also be two complements in the same case:

> Der Angeklagte ist ein Lügner.

Both, *»der Angeklagte«* and *»ein Lügner«* are in nominative case. (One is the subject, the other is an object)

> Der Staatsanwalt nennt den Angeklagten einen Lügner.

Here *»den Angeklagten«* and *»einen Lügner«* are both accusative objects.

Comment: *in seinem Schaukelstuhl* is not a prepostional object but an adverbial because it describes the place where the action takes place and can be used with almost any verb that describes some action. For the difference between adverbial an prepositional object see e.g. https://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/praepositionalobjekt-adverbial.php